# Find all $n\in\mathbb N^+$ such that the sum of the digits of $5^n$ is equal to $2^n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all $n\in\mathbb N^+$ such that the sum of the digits of $5^n$ is equal to $2^n$.

I've solved this, but I think the proof is a bit weird and I wonder if there's a better one.

---

My proof:

We can see that $n\neq 1$, $n\neq 2$, $n=3$, $n\neq 4$ and $n\neq 5$.

Let $n>5$. Notice that $5^6$ has $5$ digits, while $\frac{2^6}{9}=7\frac{1}{9}$, so $5^6$ has to have at least $8$ digits in order for the sum of the digits to be able to at least reach $2^6$.

Everytime $1$ is added to the exponent of $5$, the amount of digits $5^n$ gets is at most $1$, while $\frac{2^{n+1}}{9}-\frac{2^n}{9}=\frac{2^n}{9}>3$, so the lowest amount of digits it has to have to reach $2^n$ becomes higher by at least $4$.

When $n=6$, the amount of digits $5^n$ has is already lower than the amount it has to have in order to reach $2^n$, and I've just proved that the amount it has to have in order to reach $2^n$ grows faster than the amount of digits $5^n$ has, therefore $5^n$ will never be able to reach $2^n$ when $n>5$.

Hence the only solution is $n=3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it a little more straightforward:

let $\Sigma$ denote the sum of digits of $5^n$ for a fixed $n$

Then $\Sigma \leq 9\times (\lfloor\log_{10}(5^n)\rfloor+1)$

Which implies $\Sigma \leq 9\times (\lfloor(0.7n)\rfloor+1)$

Now it is trivial that $\forall n\geq 6,\: 9\times (\lfloor(0.7n)\rfloor+1) < 2^n$

It remains to check cases $1$ to $5$